# no-cache attribute misunderstanding

Tags: http, caching, no-cache

I am creating a http client cache, but I have a doubt about the no-cache field.

Official [documentation](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.1) says:

> If the no-cache directive does not specify a field-name, then a cache MUST NOT use the response to satisfy a subsequent request without successful revalidation with the origin server. [...]
>
> If the no-cache directive does specify one or more field-names, then a cache MAY use the response to satisfy a subsequent request, subject to any other restrictions on caching. However, **the specified field-name(s) MUST NOT be sent in the response to a subsequent request without successful revalidation with the origin server.**

My question is: how can I revalidate just those fields without revalidating the whole response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send a [conditional request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) to the origin server and use the returned (header) fields when you get a `304 Not Modified`

Comment: Then, what you say is to do the same request as if there were not field names in the no-cache attribute, and take just those fields when I receive 304 Not Modified?

Comment: Correct. but you might also get back a '2XX OK' in which case you have  to consider the response as a new entity.